# Splitting kernel huge page (THP) returned by alloc_pages()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, mmu, page-tables

I am looking for a way to split the kernel's huge page (2MiB) mappings into the smaller (4KiB) page table entries. So far, I only encountered the function [`set_memory_4k`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11-rc3/source/arch/x86/mm/pat/set_memory.c#L1957), which only works during the early boot stage (global variable `early_boot_irqs_disabled` must be true). I am a bit reluctant to disable interrupts to call this function, but I don't know of any other way to split a *kernel* (not user) page table.

The goal is to map individual 4KB pages with different permissions. However, pages returned via `alloc_pages()` are often part of 2MB mappings. I do ***not*** have an option to use any other allocator (`vmalloc`, `kmalloc`, `memblock`, ...), so I am required to use the `alloc_pages()` function or any of its variants.

**Additional information:**

I am aware of the existing function [`split_huge_page`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11-rc3/source/include/linux/huge_mm.h#L185). Unfortunately this approach is not working for `struct page`s representing kernel memory. The reason for this (according to [LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/565097/)) is that the `page->mapping` field, which is [checked](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11-rc3/source/mm/huge_memory.c#L2690) before the split, needs to be non-`NULL`. This doesn't apply to kernel pages, so this approach also only seems to work for user space pages.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure get your question clearly. I see you need is [`split_huge_pmd`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11-rc3/source/include/linux/huge_mm.h#L397) not `split_huge_page`?

Comment: `split_huge_pmd` requires a `vm_area_struct` pointer/instance, that only exists for user space processes. Since this function requires a VMA pointer, it can only be called for user space processes and not for kernel memory returned by `alloc_pages`.